# Pdf Reader+iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf-generation

i want to make PDF reader app in phone.
where i have to implement search functionality.
in which i have to take the text of one page of .pdf file and have to do search functionality.

Is anyone had done it.
Please give me the sample code.
Thanks in advance

Editing the question.....
I had done how to search the key word,but i is working on .pdf file of one single page only.But not able to do how i have to search the word in multiple page.

Example:-
If i am having the .pdf file of multiple page.And now i want to implement the search functionality.Then how can i do it.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes someone did it before. I used this kit also and it is great to search pages and highlight the result. It's [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) by KurtCode (on Github).

Comment: thanks for the reply.I had found this code.But i this i had noticed that search on only one page is there.What i have to do more.if i want to use the pdf having multiple page.How i can search the word in the.pdf file with more than 1 page.Please help me.

Comment: Make a for loop trough all the pages and display the results in a tableview. ;-) It works I did it a few days ago.

Comment: where should i do he for loop??

Comment: How to get the total number of page in the .pdf file programatically??

Comment: Look into the CGPDF API. There are all the needed methods. ;-)